# Probability that the $n$-bit number has $k$ factors

Tags: probability, number-theory, prime-numbers

**Question 1:** How we can calculate the probability that an $n$-bit number has $k$ prime factors (number of factors)?

**Question 2:** What is the average number of prime factors for an $n$-bit number?

Thank you very much for help.

Comment: It may not matter, but to be precise, you should specify whether you are counting only distinct prime factors, or prime factors including multiplicity. Thus for example $12=(2)(2)(3)$ has $2$ distinct prime factors, but $3$ prime factors including multiplicity.

Comment: Also, why do you think such an average would be known?

Comment: For an estimate, I suggest  you try writing a test program (i.e., a simulation), using a CAS system which has built-in prime factorization routines.

Comment: This may help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Kac_theorem